# smort bee honey

Tags: decanting-problems

<sub>You have decided that you want to become chubbee, but not too much.</sub>

<sub>You will need to eat exactly 10 liters of honey in order to achieve the desired effect.</sub>

---

The bees produce 10 liters of honey on request, with an additional amount as a gift.
But since bees can only count until 5 they spread the honey over multiple jars.
A 5 liter jar filled with 4, a 5 liter jar filled with 3, and a completely filled 4 liter jar.

The bee queen assures you that you can obtain exactly 10 liter with easy.
How?

Comment: Let me get this straight: I want to measure 10 litres, and I have two 5-litre jars I can use? I think the Bee Queen is absolutely correct.

Comment: @bass it was supposed to be 4/4,3/5,4/4. But i messed up somehow. The catch would be that the bees were counting base6 

Comment: Ah, yes, that sometimes happens. I fight that particular problem by (almost) never posting the question on the same day I wrote it down; looking at the puzzle after a good night's sleep pretty much always reveals some possible improvements, and sometimes even outright bugs like this. Even though answering on PSE is always a bit of a race against time, asking is different: nobody is going to post my puzzle if I delay it by a day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that 4/5 jar is *A*, 3/5 jar is *B* and 4/4 jar is *C*.
First, Get all of the honey in *C*.
**4 liter**.
Then, pour honey of *B* so that *A* is full.
Then, *B* is 2 liter.
Get all of the honey in *B*.
**6 liter**.
Then, pour honey of *A* so that *C* is full.
Then *C* is 4 liter.
Get all of the honey in *C*.
**10 liter**.

Comment: I poured all honey of C to other jar.

Comment: Thank you. How about this. I will pour honey of C so that A and B are both full. Then You can get By A and B.

Comment: your right, but i messed up the original and did the nubers wrong. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Even the puzzle as intended according to comments (A = 4/4, B = 3/5, C = 4/4) seems trivial:

- Pour honey from A into B until B is full (A = 2/4, B = 5/5, C = 4/4)
- Eat all the honey in B (A = 2/4, B = 0/5, C = 4/4)
- Pour all honey from A into B (A = 0/4, B = 2/5, C = 4/4)
- Pour honey from C into B until B is full (A = 0/4, B = 5/5, C = 1/4)
- Eat all the honey in B (A = 0/4, B = 0/5, C = 1/4)